# Xcode 4.5 command line unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, ios6, xcodebuild, xcode4.5

Having an issue since updating to Xcode 4.5 when running my unit tests via command line.
The following is the output i'm seeing when i try to run my tests

```
Unknown Device Type. Using UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad based on screen size
Terminating since there is no workspace.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:334: note: Passed tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:345: note: Completed tests for architectures 'i386'
```

Even though it does say the tests have passed and completed, I don't think they have actually have been run.

I'm using the following command to run the tests:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyAppTests -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug clean build TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES
```

Has anyone run into the same problem and can offer a solution?

Comment: I have the same issue, and other people do as well: https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit/issues/96. No solution for now.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue. It's been there since the first beta, but since it's "unsupported functionality" Apple hasn't helped with it. My solution is to write a separate OCUnit/SenTest test runner launched using WaxSim. It's partially written, but is working so far, will share once it's finished

Comment: same problem.  best i found is this (yet I have not got it working) - http://www.gerardcondon.com/blog/2012/09/20/further-jenkins-setup-code-signing/

Comment: Any news with Xcode 4.5.1? Note that I've got a bounty on a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604628/running-ios-unit-tests-from-command-line-with-xcode-4-5

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions below? I have been successful with my approach.

Comment: Any solution that doesn't involve installing additional software? Really looking for a solution that allows me to fix my current installation so that I don't have to alter my build server.

Comment: Xcode 5 supports its own continuous integration solution. Maybe this can also be accessed via other CI tools like Jenkins? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/000-About_Continuous_Integration/about_continuous_integration.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just thought I should also share what I did for a solution to this issue. I followed the solution outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10823483/666943 but converted the ruby script to shell. At the end I basically installed `ios-sim` via homebrew and replace the `Run Script` in the `Build Phases` of my Test target with the following:

```
if [ "$RUN_UNIT_TEST_WITH_IOS_SIM" = "YES" ]; then
    test_bundle_path="$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.$WRAPPER_EXTENSION"
    ios-sim launch "$(dirname "$TEST_HOST")" --setenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection --setenv XCInjectBundle="$test_bundle_path" --setenv XCInjectBundleInto="$TEST_HOST" --args -SenTest All "$test_bundle_path"
    echo "Finished running tests with ios-sim"
else
    "${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests"
fi
```

To start the test now I pass in the argument `RUN_UNIT_TEST_WITH_IOS_SIM=YES` e.g.

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyAppTests -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug clean build RUN_UNIT_TEST_WITH_IOS_SIM=YES
```

Comment: I always get the following error: `[DEBUG] Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator session timed out." UserInfo=0x7fd323c2a4a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed out.}`

Comment: If this is for jenkins as I see your other question was related to then you will require another step to get it working. When installing Jenkins on our build server, it created the launchd plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons. When trying to launch ios-sim, I encountered the same error as you described, the issue seems to be that jenkins is no run as the logged in user. By moving the launchd plist to /Library/LaunchAgents instead, so that its run as the logged in user, this solved the problem.

Comment: Nono, I tried this one without Jenkins for now. I ran it from Xcode by running the Test Scheme (I'll also try from the command line, maybe that's where the error comes from). And: I have a separate Jenkins Server and Build Node. In most cases, the `jenkins` user on the build node is *not* logged in. The server just connects to it via SSH. It used to work fine in Xcode 4.4.1 with this hack: http://www.raingrove.com/2012/03/28/running-ocunit-and-specta-tests-from-command-line.html

Comment: Ok, sorry, it works when run from the command line with the command you provide (appending `-arch i386`). Now I need to try it out with Jenkins.

Comment: The jenkins user has to be logged in for my approach.

Comment: Too bad, it's the same with the other approach using WaxSim.

Comment: Using iOS-sim from home-brew is the key to success. I can confirm, this works fine using Xcode 4.5 - though the referenced Xcode script patch needs to look a little different than quoted.

Comment: This works for me in our TeamCity environment. I installed ios-sim using Homebrew and changed the run script so it includes the absolute path for starting ios-sim.

Comment: OK I need to correct my comment: It worked fine since I rebooted the system, now I get the same error that @fabb gets.

Comment: @fabb did you run xcodebuild while the iOS simulator is in use? I also got the session timeout error in that case.

Comment: Nice one! I was stuck at the Ruby code, didn't know where to use it. So your code helped a lot! But I also have to set `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO` to pass over this error: `Check dependencies [BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).`

Comment: @Hlung. Yes that is a build setting that you can set in your project so that you don't have to specify it as part of the xcodebuild command

Comment: I have a target with a space in the name and had to fix the script to escape paths: https://gist.github.com/JohannesRudolph/5353093. Feel free to incorporate this (or improve it, my bash skills are < epsilon)

Answer (score 9):

I noticed this issue in the beta versions of Xcode 4.5 / iOS 6. I've been working on a standalone unit tests runner to work around this problem. It works by compiling your unit test bundle, then compiling a version of your app that automatically runs the unit tests in a simulator environment.

The tool is by no means complete, but enough people seem to be having this issue that I'm releasing the tool as is for now. Please fork or comment so I can improve the tool.

xcodetest: https://github.com/sgleadow/xcodetest

Also keep an eye on this radar on the issue http://openradar.appspot.com/12306879

Comment: I can confirm that Stew's answer was what helped me get unit tests running.

Comment: It works! But I had to append `-arch i386` to the two `xcodebuild` occurrences in the script.

Comment: What not works is executing other tests from a library subproject within the same scheme.

Comment: Problem: Sometimes WaxSim has a timeout before finishing its unit tests. The script still success and exit code 0.

Comment: Small problem: when several users use the script, it only works for the first one, as the others have no access to the `/tmp/xcodetest/${MAIN_APP_TARGET}` directory. This should be made unique.

Comment: I use `OUTPUT_DIR=\`mktemp -d -t "xcodetest"\`/${MAIN_APP_TARGET}` instead.

Comment: Hmmmm, running the testcases via SSH (needed for Jenkins) does *not* work. It just hangs after starting WaxSim. Running it locally works though. Some issue with WaxSim and not having a UI?

Comment: sometimes, I get this as well.
Session ended with error. The simulated application quit.

But the test still passed.

Answer (score 6):

`xcodebuild  -project ${PROJECT_PATH}/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj \
            -scheme ${TEST_SCHEME} \
            -configuration Debug \
            -sdk iphonesimulator5.1 \
                clean build \
                TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES`

Setting the iphonesimulator to version 5.1 seems to solve the problem. There are radar bugs filled upon this issue.

This article also mention a good solution to follow:

http://baolei.tumblr.com/post/32428168156/ios-unit-test-from-command-line-ios6-xcode4-5

Comment: I ended going for a solution similar to the link you provided based on  the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10823483/666943.

Comment: I guess you still needed to patch `RunPlatformUnitTests` like described here? http://www.raingrove.com/2012/03/28/running-ocunit-and-specta-tests-from-command-line.html

Comment: Yup, patching the RunPlatformUnitTests is also required. I have a sample one here: https://github.com/victorlima/AutoBuild/blob/master/scripts/RunPlatformUnitTests.patched. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Also there's little hack that can help to run command-line tests on iOS6.0 simulator SDK

I'm Using Cedar and this tweak helped me :

First, you need to update your **main** file a little:

```
  // Faking up that workspace port
  CFMessagePortCreateLocal(NULL, (CFStringRef) @"PurpleWorkspacePort", NULL, NULL,NULL);
  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"CedarApplicationDelegate");
```

Second, you need to add category to UIWindow:

```
@implementation UIWindow (Private)
- (void)_createContext {
   // Doing nothing here. Just for crash avoidance
}
@end
```

Cedar **Unittest** will run fine, with some runtime warnings, but, at least they'll be able to run :)