# Running iOS Unit Tests from Command Line with Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, jenkins, xcodebuild

While running Unit Tests from command line (necessary for Jenkins) used to work until Xcode 4.4.1 with [this hack](http://www.raingrove.com/2012/03/28/running-ocunit-and-specta-tests-from-command-line.html), it does not seem to work anymore with Xcode 4.5.

Now I get the following error message:

```
....MyTests.build/Script-641C6E0115D3BECD004175F...: line 3: 16669 Segmentation fault: 11  "${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests"
```

Any ideas how to make it work again?

Comment: similar problem and i am not finding the fix, or if apple fixed it or a hack to the hack.

Comment: And `xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme test` still does not work with iOS.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557935/xcode-4-5-command-line-unit-testing

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after updating. You have to pass the argument **RUN_UNIT_TEST_WITH_IOS_SIM=YES** to the command xcodebuild to make it work.