# Jenkins build XCode project + run unit test

Tags: jenkins, xcode4.5

I been struggling for awhile following every single article, blog post etc that I can find. 
I need to setup Jenkins to build my XCode 4.5.2 project and run the unit test... I got the build part working but not the unit test part...

I first tried the Xcode Plugin and then all the different other options to run it from the command line with xcodebuild etc which all fail...

Xcode 4.5.2 
Mac OS Lion
Jenkins CI

can anyone give me reference to something that can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a lot of people complaining that XCode 4.5 broke command line unit test execution. Here is one reference post with a possible workaround solution:
[Xcode 4.5 command line unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557935/xcode-4-5-command-line-unit-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook built a tool that might be helpful: https://github.com/facebook/xctool

If that does not work for you you will have to wait until Apple builds better tools for unit testing and continuous integration.