# Xcode: build and run for both iOS Simulator and Device in one step?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I need to get into the practice of better testing for both iOS 5 and 6.

I'd like to press one button (or one keyboard shortcut) and have Xcode build and run my app on both the iOS simulator *and* my iPhone device at once.

Is this possible?

Comment: No such feature in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it by GUI of Xcode. You probably need to launch the application from the command line. Which means create a script by any language you know (shell, python, ruby, etc...)

Here is some information: check the [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557935/xcode-4-5-command-line-unit-testing), and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403991/xcode-4-run-tests-from-the-command-line-xcodebuild), and [link3](http://www.stewgleadow.com/blog/2011/11/05/installing-ios-apps-on-the-device-from-the-command-line/) .

Hope that's helpful.