# Jenkins stops getting my unit test output from xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, jenkins

I've got Jenkins set up to build my application test target and execute tests in the iOS simulator like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403991/xcode-4-run-tests-from-the-command-line-xcodebuild/10823483#10823483) says. When I execute the build in Jenkins, the iOS simulator launches and runs all of my tests, but I only get output in the test log for the first test.

If I run xcodebuild from the command line it also runs all of my tests, but I do get output for all of the tests.

Does anybody have any idea what could be going wrong in Jenkins or suggestions for further troubleshooting? Thanks!