# How to run Xcode test using Xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I've added a new target to my project of type unit testing bundle and added some test cases.

I can run this from within Xcode but I can't figure out how to run it from the command line so that I can add it as part of a CI build system.

I know application tests cannot be executed outside of the Xcode environment, but these are not application tests but logic tests.

Whenever I try to run any xcodebuild command, even a clean, it comes back saying the scheme isn't configured for running. And to being with it wasn't - in the manage schemes section only the test checkbox was ticked, but even after ticking the run checkbox I still get the same error.

Actually I am not sure whether I am supposed to be:
a) Execute the scheme for the main project with the Test part* set to my newly created test target (*I don't know the word for this - by "part" I mean where in the manage schemes section there is a choice to execute for Build|Run|Test|Profile|Analyse|Archive.)
b) Create a new scheme just to run the tests.

I've tried both ways within Xcode and both ways work, but no matter what I try using XCodebuild I always get some error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4: Run tests from the command line (xcodebuild)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403991/xcode-4-run-tests-from-the-command-line-xcodebuild)